# How can I check the innerHTML content of a paragraph using Jasmine and Karma in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular component that has a `<p>` tag with some text.  One of the sentences inside of the paragraph is bold.  I am trying to write a unit test in Jasmine/Karma to check the `innerHTML` content.  However, all of my attempts seem to fail.  Am I going about this the wrong way?  Here is my markup and JavaScript:

Angular component HTML

```
<p>
    Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this 
    continent, <b>a new nation</b>, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the 
    proposition that all men are created equal.
</p>
```

Jasmine Unit Test

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
    let component: TestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let el: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        el = fixture.debugElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should display "a new nation" as bold text', () => {
        const boldText = el.query(By.css('p')).nativeElement;
        expect(boldText.innerHTML).toContain('<b>a new nation</b>');
    });
});
```

I get the following failed error with this code:

```
Expected 'Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, <b _ngcontent-c1="">a new nation</b>, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.'.
```

Note that Angular is injecting its own ID to the `<b>` tag.  Is this the reason is fails?  Is this even the best way to go about this kind of test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Query directly the bold text :

```
const boldText = el.query(By.css('p b')).nativeElement;
expect(boldText.textContent).toContain('a new nation');
```

Comment: I can't believe it is that easy.  That did the trick!  Thanks

Comment: It's always that easy, but sometimes it's so obvious you miss it (happened to me way too much). Good luck with your project !

Comment: getting error `Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<string>>'`